# Error starting neo4j after upgrade

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j community edition on an Ubuntu VM and had just updated the software yesterday when I started running into problems. Specifically, I cannot get the server to start. I made changes to the configuration file to allow for updates, but as you can see in the second set of messages, something went wrong in the process.

Can anyone shed some light on the error messages below? Also, where is the "attached cause exception" the message keeps referring to?

TYIA.

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@5b2894f8' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:462)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:112)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:111)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:139)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader$UnexpectedUpgradingStoreVersionException: '/var/lib/neo4j/data/graph.db/neostore.nodestore.db' has a store version number that we cannot $$annot upgrade from. Expected 'v0.A.3' but file is version '^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@'.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradableDatabase.checkUpgradeable(UpgradableDatabase.java:96)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.migrateIfNeeded(StoreUpgrader.java:149)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.upgradeStore(NeoStoreDataSource.java:636)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:527)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:452)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: what versions (old and new) you're talking about?

Comment: did you make a backup before the upgrade?

Comment: I did the unthinkable - I upgraded a bunch of stuff on the server at once with apt-get upgrade and glanced over what was being upgraded. So, I am not sure which edition I had before (2. something0, and no I did not make a backup. I didn't realize apt-get upgraded neo4j. Lesson learned. Should I rollback the upgrade?

Comment: I looked at the history.log, and what I see is neo4j: amd64 (2.2.2, 2.2.3). Does this mean I upgraded from 2.2.2 to 2.2.3?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it knows that the db is a different version from the client (hence the "Upgrade" stuff). There's a flag in the config file which controls whether it'll do the upgrade or not.

Your options are:

- Roll back the SW upgrade
- Enable the software to upgrade the db by changing the config setting

Comment: I already set the flag to allow the upgrade (see OP). The error message indicates another problem - during the upgrade the SW is having trouble identifying the version of the existing db.

Comment: Have you confirmed the config file is pointing to the right location? I've had windows CE versions change the target directory on successive starts of the db server.

Comment: Yes. I went through all the config files after the update to make sure the settings were correct. I know they are working b/c I fixed the initial error related to not having the "allow_store_upgrade=true"

Comment: Can you roll the update back? Given what you've posted so far, that seems like the most logical course of action to get things working again.

Comment: Yeah, I just reverted to an older image. I was hoping to figure out what the problem was, just in case I want to upgrade down the road.